# Combination problem with teams.

Tags: combinatorics

I am working on the following problem.

> There are $8$ teams who are going to have $4$ games with every other team. How many games are there going to be in total ?

Assuming that a pair is required to play a game, I concluded

$$4\times{{8}\choose{2}} = 112$$

was going to be the answer, but some people claim that the correct answer is $128$.

I am not sure how they got this number, can someone confirm this?

Comment: Your answer is right. We can get to $128$ by assuming that every team also plays $2$ games with itself.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks, that is a very odd way of playing a game < play with ones self

Comment: Oh, that was a joke. They probably multiplied $8$ by $8$ by $4$ and divided by $2$. Almost right idea.

Comment: I was joking, too. Playing with ones self, get it ?

Comment: The (not particularly good) pun was I am afraid deliberate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer and method are correct. Here is a slightly different way of getting the answer, that young kids can understand.

Imagine that each team plays $2$ "home" games against each of the other $7$ teams, and $2$ "away" games.

So every team plays $(2)(7)$ home games. Thus the total number of home games is $(2)(7)(8)$. But every game is a home game for somebody, so we have counted all the games once and only once.

Comment: Thanks, that was actually very useful.